# grid of images: on hover all dim but the one with the mouse over it.

Tags: html, css

I have a grid images, I'm trying to get all of the images to dim (opacity change) when I mouse over an image except then one I moused over

here is what I'm using but I just changes the opacity of the one highlighted

```
 #grid li a:hover img {
   opacity:0.3;  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  }
  .... ...
  ...
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul id="grid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
    ....
       .....
```

Comment: two rules: one to dim the grid, one to re-brighten the  image actually being hovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add This to your css

```
#grid li a:hover img {
   opacity:1;  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  }
 #grid:hover img {
   opacity:0.3;  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  }
```

Comment: I'd add a super-sexy transition, too: {transition: opacity 0.3s;}

Comment: add what ever you want to add

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery this is fairly easy:

```
$('ul#grid img').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('ul#grid img').fadeTo(0.3);
    $(this).fadeTo(1);
});
$('ul#grid img').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(0.3);
});
```

*Edit: Using only css is far better*

Answer (score 0):

Target the parent element for hover when you hover on child element.

See the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/PgUMY/

```
 #grid:hover li a img {
   opacity:0.3;  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  }

 #grid li a:hover img {
   opacity:0.9;  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  }
```